# Can't get REngine instance from R.NET

Tags: c#, .net, r

I'm trying to get set up with R.NET v1.5.12 and I ran this code as a test of just creating and initializing the object before diving into my project.

```
string rHome = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2";
string rPath = Path.Combine(rHome, @"bin\i386");

REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(rPath, rHome);

REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();

engine.Initialize();

Console.WriteLine("So far, so good.");

engine.Dispose();

Console.ReadKey();
```

The code produces no exceptions but silently fails when it tries to get an R instance using `REngine.GetInstance()`. Nothing is written to the console and the console doesn't wait for a key press. Visual Studio tells me that XX.vshost.exe exited with code 2 but doesn't say anything else.

Does anyone have any insight here? I imagine it isn't an issue with the path because I set the R path explicitly.

Comment: Can you retrieve the R.NET and compile the RDotNet project (and its dependency RDotNet.NativeLibrary) in debug mode, and test your program against it? I cannot reproduce the issue with a the couple of situations I think may have occurred. If you could narrow down where the application exits, this would be good. Application exits without stack trace may result from R native shutting down and requesting a cleanup, but there is no clear provision to provide diagnosis information.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you use the [nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET/1.5.5), as it will save you a lot of setup and path headaches.

Comment: The nuget package 1.5.5 is superseded; I doubt reverting back to it will solve this issue, and it comes with other limitations. An updated package will be available at nuget.org; being worked on currently.

Comment: @RyanGates: I downloaded `R.NET.1.5.12.nupkg` from the R.NET website and just set up Visual Studio to use a local NuGet package source.

Comment: @j-m: I downloaded the source code from the R.NET website and I tried to open R.NET.sln in Visual Studio. It says `error: The project file could not be loaded. Could not find part of the path 'C:\Users\alexa\R.NET\Graphics\RDotNet.Graphics.csproj'.` That path and file does actually exist. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: You can ignore the issue with the missing RDotNet.Graphics.csproj, so long as you have the project RDotNet.csproj compiling.

Comment: @j-m: I edited R.NET.sln to point to the correct folder for RDotNet.Graphics.csproj (I was mistaken--it was incorrect before) and I was able to build the solution successfully in debug mode. There were warnings of missing XML comments but that was it.

Comment: @Alex A. - Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @codeConcussion No, unfortunately. I ended up using a different approach since I wasn't able to get R.NET to work at the time.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem.  Calling `REngine.GetInstance()` makes the entire process exit silently with code 2.

I investigated source code of R.NET and R3.2.2, then found that:

1. `REngine.GetInstance()` calls the native function `setup_Rmainloop()` in R.dll
2. `setup_Rmainloop()` calls `exit()` when it cannot open "base" library file at 
   "%R_HOME%/library/base/R/base", with exit code 2.

I suggest you to check if `fopen("%R_HOME%/library/base/R/base", "r")` (or any equivalent code) fails or not.

Comment: Has this problem been solved? For me it did, since i had some right issues concerning my R installation path, which were revealed by trying to open the file.